# Spring Batch Not persisting Data Properly in MYSQL Database

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I am fairly new to Spring batch so maybe I am missing something. After running this spring batch I cannot seem to persist the data(List) in database(Order_Summary_Details Table) This is my SpringBatchConfig class-

```java
package com.spring.data.jpa.arkabrata.Config;

import com.spring.data.jpa.arkabrata.Entity.OrderSummary;
import com.spring.data.jpa.arkabrata.Repository.OrderSummaryRepository;
import com.spring.data.jpa.arkabrata.Service.OrderProductParticipantServiceImpl;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScope;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.builder.JobBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.builder.StepBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.data.RepositoryItemWriter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SpringBatchConfig {

    @Autowired
    private OrderProductParticipantServiceImpl orderProductParticipantService;

    public SpringBatchConfig() throws SQLException {
    }


    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public OrderProductReader itemReader(@Value("#{jobParameters['orderDate']}") String orderDate) throws Exception {
        log.info("Entering OrderProductReader with orderDate value-->"+" "+orderDate);
        List<Map<String, Object>> groupedData = orderProductParticipantService.getDataByDate(orderDate);
        OrderProductReader orderProductReader = new OrderProductReader(groupedData);
        log.info("Leaving OrderProductReader-->");
        List<Map<String,Object>> returnedValue= orderProductReader.read();
        System.out.println("returnedValue = " + returnedValue);
        return orderProductReader;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public OrderAmountProcessor processor() throws Exception {
        log.info("Entering OrderAmountProcessor-->");
        List<Map<String, Object>> groupedData = orderProductParticipantService.getDataByDate("1970-01-01");
        OrderAmountProcessor orderAmountProcessor = new OrderAmountProcessor();
        List<OrderSummary> returnedValue= orderAmountProcessor.process(groupedData);
        System.out.println("returnedValue = " + returnedValue);
        log.info("Leaving OrderAmountProcessor-->");
        return orderAmountProcessor;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public OrderSummaryItemWriter writer(){
        log.info("At writer, getting inside OrderSummaryItemWriter--->");
        return new OrderSummaryItemWriter();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step(JobRepository jobRepository,
                           PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) throws Exception {
        return new StepBuilder("step", jobRepository)
                .<List<Map<String, Object>>, List<OrderSummary>>chunk(10, transactionManager)
                .reader(itemReader("1970-01-01"))
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job myJob(JobRepository jobRepository, Step step) {
        return new JobBuilder("myJob", jobRepository)
                .start(step)
                .build();
    }
}
```

This is my ItemReader class-

```java
package com.spring.data.jpa.arkabrata.Config;

import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.NonTransientResourceException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ParseException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.UnexpectedInputException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class OrderProductReader implements ItemReader<List<Map<String, Object>>> {

    private final List<Map<String, Object>> resultList;
    public OrderProductReader(List<Map<String, Object>> resultList) {
        this.resultList = resultList;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Map<String, Object>> read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
        return resultList;
    }
}
```

My ItemProcessor class-

```java
package com.spring.data.jpa.arkabrata.Config;
import com.spring.data.jpa.arkabrata.Entity.OrderSummary;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
@Slf4j
public class OrderAmountProcessor implements ItemProcessor<List<Map<String, Object>>, List<OrderSummary>> {

    @Override
    public List<OrderSummary> process(List<Map<String, Object>> orderProductDetails) throws Exception {
            List<OrderSummary> orderSummaryList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Map<String, Object> orderProductDetail : orderProductDetails)
            {
                log.info("I AM INSIDE PROCESS METHOD");
                OrderSummary orderSummary = new OrderSummary();
                Long totalQuantity = (Long) orderProductDetail.get("quantity");
                BigDecimal price = (BigDecimal) orderProductDetail.get("price");
                String productName = (String) orderProductDetail.get("productName");
                Date orderDate = new Date(19700101);
                if (orderProductDetail.get("orderDate") instanceof Date) {
                    orderDate = (Date) orderProductDetail.get("orderDate");
                }
                orderSummary.setProductQuantity(totalQuantity);
                orderSummary.setAmount(price.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(totalQuantity)));
                orderSummary.setOrderDate(orderDate);
                orderSummary.setProductName(productName);
       /*Long totalQuantity = ord
               BigDecimal totalPrice = orderProductParticipant.getPrice();
        orderSummary.setAmount(totalPrice.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(totalQuantity)));
        orderSummary.setOrderDate(orderProductParticipant.getOrder().getOrderDate());
        orderSummary.setProductName(orderProductParticipant.getProduct().getProductName());
        orderSummary.setProductQuantity(orderProductParticipant.getQuantity());*/
                orderSummaryList.add(orderSummary);
            }
            return orderSummaryList;
    }
}
```

And my ItemWriter class-

```java
package com.spring.data.jpa.arkabrata.Config;

import org.springframework.batch.item.Chunk;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.spring.data.jpa.arkabrata.Entity.OrderSummary;
import com.spring.data.jpa.arkabrata.Repository.OrderSummaryRepository;

import java.util.List;

@Component
public class OrderSummaryItemWriter implements ItemWriter<List<OrderSummary>> {

    @Autowired
    private OrderSummaryRepository orderSummaryRepository;

    @Override
    public void write(Chunk<? extends List<OrderSummary>> items) throws Exception {
        for (List<OrderSummary> chunk : items) {
            orderSummaryRepository.saveAll(chunk);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong? Even if I don't use stepscope and pass the parameter in ItemReader manually the debug points atleast go to the itemreader,writer and processor methods. The itemreader() method also returns value as expected. but from the processor it all goes down and the processor is not returning anything apparently so the writer is also saving nothing.

If i use stepScope annotation then the debug doesn't even go inside those methods. Can you help me how to properly setup these classes so I can persist data in database properly?

Comment: How are you launching the job? Going into the bean methods means nothing that is just configuration, also why this setup instead of reading directly the right object? That way you only need the reader and writer? This seems a bit of a weird setup (and kind of beats the purpose of Spring Batch).

Comment: I am reading from a database table which has fk relations with other tables. So it has been done using Querycriteria. orderProductParticipantService.getDataByDate(orderDate) returns the necessary data as a list of map only. Also the processor is essential to do some calculations based on the data. If you go through the processor class you can see the amount is calculated by multiplying quantity and price. Then only i am mapping necessary fields to the entity object of my output table. I don't understand your question about launching the job? This is currently run as a springboot application.

Comment: Running the application doesn't run the job. Do the mapping in your query not in a processor, this job will not work when you increase the number of rows, you will run out of memory because you cannot do paging.

Comment: Understood, how do you suggest I run this job from command line/console?

Comment: Well normally if there is just 1 job it would launch it automatically. If you got multiple jobs you would need to specify which job to launc by specifying `spring.batch.job.name` in your `application.properties` or as a commandline argument.

Comment: I currently have only one job so when i start my spring boot application it should be working right? Or do I still need to explicitly mention the job class in my application.Properties?

Comment: If you haven't accidentily disabled the auto configuration it should run automatically. But I haven't seen all of your configuration.

Comment: I will update this question with all the rest of the necessary classes and an ER diagram of the data model as well. Thank you for being so responsive.